# To XML files comparsion Java

Tags: java, xml, file

I'm using the FC command to compare the content of two files, and my program works fine but I need to make it ignore some paricular charcters such as ?? in some places, if somebody can help...that would be grate...

Best Regards

```
public void runSystemCommand(String command) {
        try {
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader errorStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));

            String strLn = "";

            // reading output stream of the command
            while ((strLn = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(strLn);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `String.replaceAll()` for each line read from the buffers.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the best answer here might be to do some pre-processing on the files, to remove those characters, and then compare the files with those removed. If the files aren't too huge, I'd say that would be the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `fc` if you want to compare XML files in java try [XMLUnit](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/).